# How to do a left or subquery with this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a a few `left join` and so I would like to add/merge this `sql` inside my other query:

```
SELECT
    A.ID
FROM 
    Table1 as A 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         T.ID, T.TRF_TAKEN,
         SUM(CASE WHEN CAST([UNT_TRNSFER] AS FLOAT) = 0 
                  THEN CAST([TRF_TAKEN] AS FLOAT) 
                  ELSE ISNULL([UNT_TRNSFER], 0) 
             END) AS 'UNT_TRNSFER'
     FROM TRNS_C as T
     GROUP BY ID;) ON A.ID = TransfC.ID
WHERE
    A.ID = 1;
```

ERROR

> Column 'TRNS_C.TRF_TAKEN' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` from `GROUP BY ID;)`, add `T.TRF_TAKEN` to `GROUP BY` clause and add the table alias `Transfc` that you joined on.

```
SELECT A.ID, Transfc.UNT_TRNSFER
FROM Table1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  T.ID, T.TRF_TAKEN,
            SUM(CASE WHEN CAST([UNT_TRNSFER] AS FLOAT) = 0 THEN CAST([TRF_TAKEN] AS FLOAT)
            ELSE ISNULL([UNT_TRNSFER], 0) END) AS 'UNT_TRNSFER'
            FROM TRNS_C as T
            GROUP BY T.ID, T.TRF_TAKEN
) Transfc
ON A.ID = TransfC.ID
WHERE A.ID = 1;
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't see the column `'UNT_TRNSFER` not even empty

Comment: @AMaduro thats because you didnt specify that column in the `SELECT` statement. see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your non aggregated fields into the GROUP BY.  You are asking it to group by EMPLID but you are only selecting t.ID and t.TRF_Taken.

```
select A.ID
from Table1 as A 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T.ID, T.TRF_TAKEN,
            SUM(CASE WHEN CAST([UNT_TRNSFER] AS FLOAT) = 0 THEN CAST([TRF_TAKEN] AS FLOAT) ELSE ISNULL([UNT_TRNSFER], 0) END) AS 'UNT_TRNSFER'
            FROM TRNS_C as T
            GROUP BY T.ID, T.TRF_TAKEN;
    ) Transfc
ON A.ID = TransfC.ID
    Where A.ID = 1;
```

Comment: Helpful.  Error message?

Comment: Added the alias to my code above.  You asked the query to join on Transfc but did not name the subquery with that alias.

Comment: didn't work,  Maybe I am missing something in my query

Comment: doesn't show error but is not showing the column either

Answer (score 0):

As a note, the query in your question is probably equivalent to:

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM Table1 A 
WHERE A.ID = 1;
```

The only thing your `left join` might be doing is multiplying the number of rows.  It seems unlikely that that is desirable.